# UTF-8 Spanish Characters Not Displaying

Tags: php, utf-8, mime-types

I am trying desperately to get Spanish characters to show correctly in a MIME email I am sending.

So after a few hours of searching I have tried the following to no success.

1. Added the following to my PHP:

   ```
   mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
   ```
2. Ensured that my file is in UTF8 in notepad++
3. Added the following to my HTML code:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
   ```
4. Added the following to my my.cnf file and restarted the server:

   ```
   init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
   ```
5. Ensured that all tables are in utf8_unicode_ci
6. Added the following to queries before the select query:

   ```
   SET NAMES utf8;
   ```
7. I am using mime to send the emails with the following code:

   ```
   // Creating the Mime message
   $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);

   // Setting the body of the email
   $mime->setTXTBody($body);
   $mime->setHTMLBody($html);
   $headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to,
                   'Subject' => $subject, 
                   "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
   $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
       'port' => $port,
       'auth' => true,
       'username' => $username,
       'password' => $password));

   $body = $mime->get();
   $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

   $recipients = $to.", ".$bcc;
   $mail = $smtp->send($recipients , $headers, $body);
   ```

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: How do you send email?

Comment: try by adding AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 to your .htaccess file

Comment: @ZahidulHosseinRipon Won't help, he is trying to send utf8 email, AddDefaultCharset sets charset for browser.

Comment: Also worth trying mysqli::set_charset() http://us2.php.net/mysqli_set_charset since you appear to be reading from a MySQL database - theoretically `SET NAMES utf8` should have this covered though.

Comment: @Marek I am using mime for the email and just added my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't go with your own solutions to compose and send email, you are likely to get it wrong. Use some email class, for example [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer). There just set CharSet property:

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
```

Or [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html)

According to [documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.mail-mime.php), you can pass head_charset, text_charset and html_charset params. The content type header you pass to $mime->headers() is likely overwritten.

Comment: +1 The problem is likely not in your script charset, but in sent email headers containing wrong content type. It won't be set to utf-8 magically. Using PHPMailer will fix that

Comment: I am using mime, I just updated my question.  Any idea how to make it work in MIME?

Comment: What's the $mime object? $mime = new ??? Mime is the standard, there might be a php class with that name, but I'm not going to look for it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simple: UTF-8 sucks when using spanish, you must use 8859-15.

UTF-8 is for english language mostly and even if english language uses latin numbers and letters obligated by Julious Ceasar and the Roman Empire the creators just don't care about latin languages (really funny) and claim it is international HTML5 ready and all that crap.

Maybe the creator's world is limited to USA and that is all they know about the world. But the world out there is bigger and better and I hope they understand that and a new UTF-9 rolls out ...

Even the HTML5 validator believes that:

```
Legacy encoding iso-8859-15 used. Documents should use UTF-8.
```

Now if you want to use spanish in your super professional international standard UTF-8 then you must the follow:

Encode each symbol like this otherwise it won't work:

```
á -> &aacute;
é -> &eacute;
í -> &iacute;
ó -> &oacute;
ú -> &uacute;
ñ -> &ntilde;
```

Who the h... created UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  It was a problem with the mime email.

```
    // Creating the Mime message
    $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
    // Setting the body of the email
    $mime->setTXTBody($body);
    $mime->setHTMLBody($html);
    $mimeparams=array(); 

    $mime->addAttachment($filename,'application/pdf');

    //set SMTP server details - Using keys from www.protectedtrust.com 
    $port = "25";
    $host = "in.mailjet.com";
    $username = "fcb0ee027e8cc30b1a47caf9c6272db1";
    $password = "fe80add357c21cae0133632c4c25177a";

    //prepare message elements and send
    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject, 
    'Content-Type' => "text/html;charset=utf-8", 
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8bit'
    );

    $mimeparams['text_encoding']="8bit"; 
    $mimeparams['text_charset']="UTF-8"; 
    $mimeparams['html_charset']="UTF-8"; 
    $mimeparams['head_charset']="UTF-8"; 

    $body = $mime->get($mimeparams);    

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
    array ('host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));

    $body = $mime->get();
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

    $recipients = $to.", ".$bcc;
    $mail = $smtp->send($recipients , $headers, $body);
```